# Changing contents of a file through shell script with special symbols

Tags: bash, shell, sed

i have file and it content following line using shell script

```
 define("SVC_OS_URL", "http://abc.bbc.com:9090");
```

i want to change it as following

```
define("SVC_OS_URL", "http://bbc.uuu.com:8989");
```

this is my shell script code

SVC_OS_URL="bbc.uuu.com:8989"
sed -i -e "s/(SVC_OS_URL\", \"http://=)/$SVC_OS_URL\"/" config.php

but this command didn't work 
any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alternate regex delimiter and fix your regex pattern:

```
sed -i -E "s~(SVC_OS_URL\", \"http://).*~\1$SVC_OS_URL\");~" config.php
```

This will give:

```
define("SVC_OS_URL", "http://bbc.uuu.com:8989");
```

Comment: how can i cheange this <base href="/"> to <base href="/shell/"

Comment: It can be done same way. Just use `~` as regex delimiter.